# Passing "this" into the $.trim() function

Tags: jquery, this

Jquery in Action has the following code:

```
$('#someField').val($.trim($('#someField').val()));
```

When I rewrite as follows though, the code does not work.

```
$('#someField').val($.trim($(this));
```

Can anyone help me understand why this does not work?

Comment: $('#someField').val($.trim($(this).val());

Comment: @Rolice: If you have an answer, post it as an answer please.

Comment: So why don't you follow the example in your book? In your code $(this) does not reffer to string object

Comment: Sorry, about that. Next time I will :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two reasons:

- `trim` takes a string, not a jQuery object. You'd need `$(this).val()` at least.
- The selector is not encapsulating a function, so `this` actually doesn't get set to the object you selected. `this` is whatever it was anyway.

The best solution is this:

```
var $obj = $('#someField');
$obj.val($.trim($obj.val()); // trim object's value
```

Answer (score 0):

When you execute that code, `this` refers to the owner of whatever function you're in.

`$(this)`, then, will never resolve to text, where `$('#someField').val()` will.

Comment: not entirely correct.  *"In JavaScript `this` always refers to the “owner” of the function"* — http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

Comment: Indeed, which is likely to be the `DOMWindow`.

Comment: -1, "this" refers to the object being acted upon, not the function you're in. onClick(this) is the object clicked, not the onClick function.

Comment: @Greg: Your example makes no sense. The reason you pass this in native onclick handlers is because `this` no longer refers to the object clicked inside the function. http://jsfiddle.net/FwXt7/1/

Answer (score 0):

`$('#someField').val()` retrieves the text of somefield, hence trim works as it is working on a string.

`$(this)` is just a jQuery object (`this` referring to the context in which it is called), hence `trim` has no meaning on it.

Answer (score 0):

`$.trim` expects to receive a string as an argument. `$(this)` is not a string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be in another function for the this keyword to change. For example:

```
$('div').slideToggle(1000, function() { // notice the function keyword
    // Now the this keyword has changed, notice the indentation due to the function
    $(this).css('border', '1px solid black'); // Here's how we use this
});
```

Of course the fact that `this` in the previous example changed to the object that we animated was something that jQuery did for us, it's not automatic. While it is possible for something like this to work:

```
$('#someField').val(function() { $.trim($(this).val()); } );
```

jQuery chooses not to let you pass a function as a parameter to the `.val()` method since it won't normally be used that way and therefore what you're trying doesn't work.

EDIT:

Now that I think about it, it wouldn't be to hard to implement:

```
var _val = $.fn.val;
$.fn.val = function(a) {
    return (!a || typeof a === 'string') ?
        _val.call(a) :
        _val.call(this, a.call( this.val() ));
}
```

[**Duck Punching by Paul Irish (read it!)**](http://paulirish.com/2010/duck-punching-with-jquery/)

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: because then you can do this `$('textarea').val($.trim);`

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: paste this to the address bar: `javascript: function go() { $('[value=7111706]').next().fadeOut(1000, function() { $(this).fadeIn(1000) }) }; setInterval(go, 2000); go();`

Comment: Are you trying to hack me?! (On a serious note, I'd be interested to see how you managed to get jQuery into scope in my address bar in an arbitrary context)

Answer (score -1):

When $.trim is hit, `this` is no longer the `#someField` element but rather, the `DOMWindow`. This is because `$` resides in the `DOMWindow` and not your `#someField` element

Comment: Not "no longer". It never was.

Comment: True. I'll be the first to say that I don't know the inner workings of js, but what I meant was that it doesn't refer to the same `this` as the `$('#someField').val` function

Comment: It does. Don't confuse functions with function _calls_. The OP is not using `this` inside a different function... only as a parameter in function calls, all within the one function (or global scope) that encompasses the code he provided.

Comment: In fact, thinking about it, "`$` resides in the `DOMWindow`" is misleading, too. The first portion of qwertymk's answer will be useful for you.

Comment: ty for the info, Tomalak. Like I said, I have a lot to learn. :P but it's questions like these that really help in that.  Thank you for the info!